# How to create database table insert data in monthly including calculation

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I'm creating a system which is staff can submit their evaluate marks of the maintenance work of golf course in monthly. The evaluation in each hole.Marks will insert in 1 to 5 marks in each hole.

The column are the category of job, job of work, frequency,hole1,hole2, hole3, hole4.

Moreover, the category of job, job of work, frequency can insert new and can be updated by user if needed.

After evaluating marks need to calculate each hole job have been done in percentage. I decide total all the marks in divide how many jobs have.

However, my issue is with the DB Design, I don't know how to design it to make it work.

So far my Idea is:

(No. varchar(5), JobCategory varchar(15), JobLocation Varchar(15), Hole1 int, Hole2 int, Hole3 int, Hole4 int, Hole5 int, Marks int)

but how do I record in monthly? **because i have already key in all the category, job, frequency left hole(marks) only enter by user**
[image]

I need enter my marks something like this
[image]

Could anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it appears you have very limited knowledge of database design. For instance, you would not create 12 tables. You would create one table with all of the same information plus a datetime field to allow for the search of records from date to date.

Comment: For example
`SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE MONTH(columnName) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND YEAR(columnName) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
`

Comment: I just new to database, so you mean i need add two more column which are month and year? Currently, i have the column are the category of job, job of work, frequency,hole1,hole2, hole3, hole4.Is it right?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your database design is a bit confusing.
You're probably better off using a single table and adding a time variable for each entry

if I understand it correctly it should be something like this:

```
people (table)
    id (int)    
    JobCategory (int id with reference to other table) (or varchar if there's few entries)
    JobLocation (int id with reference to other table) (or varchar if there's few entries)

games (table)
    id (each game has it's own id)
    person (id of the person, referencing people table)
    Hole1-5 (multiple columns)
    Marks (int)
    *timestamp (to record the time)
    *month (if you'll never need data beyond the month)
```

That way you can GROUP BY month (or use a more elaborate query for the timestamp

Though if you really want to keep the current stucture, you'll need a lot of JOIN statements for each table.

I hope that helped a little. I'm still slightly confused on what you're trying to do exactly.